# QGraphicsView.fitInView() not working as expected

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Why would the QGraphicsView.fitInView() work only after I resize the window?

I am using Python 2.7.7 and Qt 4.8.7 on MS Windows 10.  Below is the code to demonstrate the problem.

Thank you for sharing your insights and help.
Olaf

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class Test(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(Test, self).__init__(*args)

        self.setObjectName("Form")
        self.resize(200, 100)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.graphicsView = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self)
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsView, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        deltaX = 40
        deltaY = 40
        width = 200 - deltaX
        height = 200 - deltaY

        print 'constructor start'
        scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        for i in range(5):
            scene.addLine(0, i*deltaY, width, i*deltaY)
            scene.addLine(i*deltaX, 0, i*deltaX, height)
        self.graphicsView.setScene(scene)
        self.graphicsView.fitInView(scene.sceneRect(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        print 'constructor end'

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        print 'resize event start'
        scene = self.graphicsView.scene()
        r = scene.sceneRect()
        print '  rect %d %d %d %d' % (r.x(), r.y(), r.width(), r.height())
        self.graphicsView.fitInView(r, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        print 'resize event end'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    a.setActiveWindow(w)
    w.show()
    a.exec_()
```

Answer (score 6):

When a widget is first initialized, it (usually, but that depends on a lot of things) receives a resizeEvent *before* being actually shown.

The solution is to implement the resize also when the [`showEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#showEvent) is called (which happens everytime the widget or its top level parent is shown by calling `show()` or `setVisible(True)`:

```
    def updateView(self):
        scene = self.graphicsView.scene()
        r = scene.sceneRect()
        print '  rect %d %d %d %d' % (r.x(), r.y(), r.width(), r.height())
        self.graphicsView.fitInView(r, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        print 'resize event start'
        self.updateView()
        print 'resize event end'

    def showEvent(self, event):
        # ensure that the update only happens when showing the window
        # programmatically, otherwise it also happen when unminimizing the
        # window or changing virtual desktop
        if not event.spontaneous():
            print 'show event'
            self.updateView()
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly, even when transferred to Python 3.8. Thank you!

Comment: @Edgecase The python version has absolutely nothing to do with it. What matters is the *Qt* version, since PyQt (just like PySide) is a Python *binding* around the Qt toolkit (which knows anything about Python). What should be eventually pointed out is that the solution works no matter the python version, at least for this case, even for Qt5 (PyQt5/PySide2) and Qt6 (PyQt6/PySide6), since it doesn't deal with binding issues or major changes in the API related to the mentioned classes.